# Match multiple patterns in unknow order with Expect.pm

Tags: perl, expect

I am currently working on a script to automate the configuration of servers. I use the `Expect.pm` module to interact with the server but now I am facing a problem I don't know how to solve.

What I am trying to do is to `send` a command to the server that will list devices currently installed on the server, and then check if certain items are in that list. The problems is that the list is in random order so I can't know what item I should expect first.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to find all items and then exit the `expect` call when all items has been matched. Keep in mind that every server has its own set of devices and the number of devices I have to match can vary, so the solution has to solve the general case. Is there a way to accomplish this with `Expect.pm`? I have tried for some time now and I can't seem to find a good solution...

Thanks in advance!

/Haso

**EDIT: I have found a solution**

I have writen a function that will construct the array of arguments for the `expect` call and then make the call. The reference `$self` in this case is my own defined object but `$self->{_expect}` is the expect object.

```
sub match_all {
    my $self = shift;
    my $timeout = shift;
    my @patterns = @_;

    my $pattern_count = @patterns;
    my $match_count = 0;

    #Function that is called when a pattern is matched
    sub match{
        my $exp = shift;
        my $mc_ptr = shift;
        my $pc_ptr = shift;
        $$mc_ptr++;
        if($$mc_ptr != $$pc_ptr) {
            #Set the accumelator to the before and after string,
            #effectivly cutting away the matched substring.
            my $before = $exp->before();
            my $after = $exp->after();
            $exp->set_accum($before.$after);
            exp_continue_timeout;
        }
    }

    #Build the array of patterns for the expect call
    my @exp_patterns;
    foreach my $pattern (@patterns) {
        push @exp_patterns, [$pattern, \&match, \$match_count, \$pattern_count];
    }

    #Set notransfer to True in order to manipulate
    #the accumelator on my own during this function
    $self->{_expect}->notransfer(1);
    $self->{_expect}->expect($timeout, @exp_patterns);
    $self->{_expect}->notransfer(0);

    return $match_count == $pattern_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> set of devices

That's the magic word. Use [Set::Scalar](http://p3rl.org/Set%3a%3aScalar).

If `$expect_devices->is_subset($known_devices)`, you have your "match".

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The solution you are suggestion is indeed a solution to the problem, altough it was not really what is was looking for. The problem is that in order to use this solution I have to parse the list in order to create the set. Also I have to wait for the full timeout before testing if all items are in the set.